# To remove empty option from filter in CgridView Filter -Yii1

Tags: filter, yii, yii-extensions, cgridview, yii1.x

I would like to remove the empty or first option of list data value. I have `FruitList` model and it has a list, so I need to prevent from users to select all.

But now the problem is the empty option that can let user to select all Fruits, so how can I remove.

This is my code

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(

         array(
            'header' => 'Buyer',
            'name' => 'Buyer',
            'value' => 'customer_name',
            'filter' => $fruits
        ),
        array(
            'header' => 'Fruits',
            'name' => 'fruit_id',
            'value' => '$data->Buyers->FruitList->Name',
            'filter' => $fruits
        ),
        array(            
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default filters for `CGridView` renders dropdown with empty option to allow disabling filtering. But you can overwriting this behavior by providing your own dropdown as a filter:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(

         array(
            'header' => 'Buyer',
            'name' => 'Buyer',
            'value' => 'customer_name',
            'filter' => CHtml::activeDropDownList($model, 'customer_name', $fruits),
        ),
        array(
            'header' => 'Fruits',
            'name' => 'fruit_id',
            'value' => '$data->Buyers->FruitList->Name',
            'filter' => CHtml::activeDropDownList($model, 'fruit_id', $fruits)
        ),
        array(            
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
```

Make sure that you set default value for these filters in your model - something like this in your controller:

```
// ...
$model->fruit_id = FruitList::DEFAULT_ID;
$model->customer_name = FruitList::DEFAULT_ID;
if (isset($_GET['FruitList'])) {
    $model->setAttributes($_GET['FruitList']);
}
$dataProvider = $model->search();
// ...
```

Comment: Solved the issue.Thank you.-@rob006

Answer (score 0):

you can set condition in the dataProvider so its return you a result of all not null value.for example
$dataProvider->criteria->addCondition('fruit_id IS NOT NULL ');
I hope its work!